# Aerogear Unified Push not filtering by alias

Tags: java, android, push, aerogear

I´m using `Aerogear 1.0.3` server and `unifiedpush-java-client-1.1.0-alpha.1`.

I send a message using this code:

```
pushSender.send(
    UnifiedMessage.withCriteria()
        .aliases("IDOREALLYPUTHEREASINGLEALIASWITHASINGLEROW")
        .message()
        .userData("payload", newMsg)
        .build());
```

The message is received by the two installations registered even when filtered by alias.

Am I doing something wrong? How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the 1.0.3 version of the AeroGear Unified Push Server could you try using the 1.0.0 version of the Sender.

I know there was some API changes in the 1.1.x series

The 1.0.0 sender is slightly different in terms of usage for the aliases,  https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-unifiedpush-java-client/tree/1ffa6f8fd757d3918f248cce487d959a10edcca9#send-a-message